# How can I find element having an email address as class name using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, classname

How can I find an element having an email address as class name.
Email address is dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //not working getting error
  var email="abc@gmail.com";
  $("#main").find("."+email);
  //not working
  $("#main").find("."+escapeSelecorchars(email));
});

function escapeSelecorchars = function(val) {
  return val.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g,"\\\\$&");
};
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="abc@gmail.com"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `data-attr()` instead of putting the email value to class

Comment: but the how to find the element can you give example

Comment: but that thing is only the unique thing to indentify the element

Comment: *"but the how to find the element can you give example"* With an attribute selector. https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: You cannot use @ in selector name and (.)period can be use to declare the  class in the beginning of the selector name.

Comment: @pareshm check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/z9y4fdxy/)

Comment: Btw, the issue is actually that have too many ``\`` in your replacement value. If you use `"\\$&"` it works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/tvqg4nhg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try something like this

Js:

```
$(function() {
  var email = "abc@gmail.com";
  var div = $("#main").find("div[data-email='"+email+"']");
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="main">
  <div data-email="abc@gmail.com"></div>
</div>
```

Here is a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/BDo9SvksNIfCLa6I0HfI

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's probably not the best idea to use an email address as a class. However, the only reason your escaping approach doesn't work is because you are escaping incorrectly. You have too many `\` in your replacement value.

It should be

```
function escapeSelecorchars(val) {
  return val.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]/g,"\\$&");
};
```

and then [it works](https://jsfiddle.net/tvqg4nhg/).

Answer (score 1):

Because of special characters it is difficult to find element.

Checkout this code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //not working getting error
var ele = $("#main").find("div[data-email='abc@gmail.com']");
 
 
 console.log($(ele).attr('data-email'))

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <div data-email="abc@gmail.com" class="email"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want find only one div and cannot use each loop

Answer (score 0):

Use **[Attribute Equals Selector [class="value"”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**

```
console.log($('#main > div[class="abc@gmail.com"]').length);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($('#main > div[class="abc@gmail.com"]').length);
  
  $("#main").find("div[class='abc@gmail.com']").html("Appended");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
     <div class="abc@gmail.com"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic changed ?

Comment: Do you mean you took email in variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#main div').filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('class') == 'abc@gmail.com'});
```

or

```
$('div').filter(function(){ return $(this).attr('class') == 'abc@gmail.com'});
```